# Как в SQL вывести буквы английского алфавита по одной букве в каждой строке?

Tags: sql, oracle

Как вывести буквы английского алфавита (1 столбец, по одной букве в каждой строке).

Comment: С чем у вас возникли сложности?

Comment: Необходимо не отсортировать, а написать код, который выведет просто алфавит.

Comment: И с чем у вас возникли сложности во время написания скрипта(в SQL больше принято говорить скрипт или запрос)? Кстати, про сортировку, а где она вообще упоминается?

Comment: Суть в том, что я не знаю, как его написать)) Ранее не сталкивался с такими задачами. Про сортировку просто написал, для понимания. Не понимаю, что писать. SQL не так давно изучаю

Comment: Для начала напишите select, затем посмотрите, как получить симовол по его коду например(Подскажу - функция `CHR()`) и выборку из таблицы `dual`, Далее все зависит от вашей степени погруженности в Oracle, либо используете конструкцию `level`, либо 26 раз дублируете селест через union

Comment: Мой вопрос решился, когда я узнал о таблице dual. Огромное спасибо

Comment: Не надо удалять вопросы после получения ответа.

Answer (score 2):

Запрос выводит букву английского алфавита по номеру символа. Одна буква в одной строке:

```
SELECT CHR(64 + ROWNUM) ENGLISH_CHAR FROM dual
connect by level <= 26
UNION ALL
SELECT CHR(96 + ROWNUM) FROM dual
connect by level <= 26
```

Comment: ENGLISH_CHAR кажется лишним

Answer (score 0):

Ничего нового, просто размышления на тему

```
SELECT ASCII_CODE, CHR(ASCII_CODE)
FROM (SELECT ROWNUM + 64 ASCII_CODE FROM dual connect by level <= 58)
WHERE NOT ASCII_CODE BETWEEN 91 AND 96
```

или так

```
SELECT CASE X WHEN 1 THEN CHR(N) ELSE LOWER(CHR(N)) END W
FROM 
  (SELECT ROWNUM X FROM dual connect by level <=2),
  (SELECT ROWNUM + 64 N FROM dual connect by level <=26)
```